# How to refresh a single cell in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I would like to refresh a single cell in ag-grid. Using the gridApi.refreshCells().

This refresh is called by a piece of code that keeps track of the current and previous cell.
So what i would like to do it is to update the previous cell.

I tried the following:

```
gridApi.refreshCells({columns: [prevColumn], rowNodes: [prevRowNode]});
```

Note that the prevColumn is of type "Column" and prevRowNode is of type "RowNode"

Calling this works, except that it will refresh an entire column and not just a single cell.

Also refreshing a single row is also not working, which when modifying the above to just use the rowNodes  will still update the column.

Thanks you guys!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you are aiming for.  To refresh one cell have you tried gridApi.applyTransaction?
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/data-update-transactions/

Specifically the example:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/data-update-transactions/#example-updating-with-transaction

If this isn't what you need, please could you provide a plunker demonstrating the issue?

Comment: I believe what you pointed out is for data updates and is only available for version 23.1.0+ of the ag-grid. We are currently using v20 and currently can't be upgraded. The goal i m trying to achive is to call a update to a specific cell so that the cellStyleRule gets updated (Based on changes in the context of the program). This is not a problem when pressing on a cell or when data changes. The reason why I would like to update a single cell is that the grid is huge and the styling is not updated instantly when refreshCell() runs for a column or the entire grid.

Comment: @Felix I have the same use case as you, did you figure out a solution?